# How does success/failure in Icon differ from boolean values in other languages?

Tags: icon-language

I have some difficulties to understand the concept of failure and success in the **Icon** programming language. See the highlighted part below from a tutorial for Icon https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/docs/ipd266.htm.   How does success/failure in Icon differ from boolean values in other languages?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `find` returned a boolean signifying success/failure, it wouldn't be able to also return "the position at which `"or"` occurs in `line`". In languages like C, this can be worked around by taking and modifying an out parameter, but this is awkward and error-prone. In languages with algebraic datatypes, you could have the function return something like `Option<Int>`. Icon encodes "optionality" and the corresponding control flow on the language level – not only can any function fail, but control structures (like `if`) work by detecting and handling failures. (This distinguishes it from languages where values are "nullable", but null values simply crash the program or cause an exception to be thrown.)